# How to find shortes path and visit them once

Tags: python

I have a list of cities and distances between them:

```
NewYork- Los Angeles 2 441 minutes
NewYork- Los Angeles 1500 minutes
NewYork- Dallas 100 minutes
Los Angeles Washington 2456
Los Angeles Dallas 2435
```

the task is to find the shortes path to start from NYC and end in NYC and visit every city only once.
I have a list, not a graph. I have so much data (200 records) so i cant make a graph out of them and solve it like Traveling Salesman Problem. How to find shortes path?

Comment: Why can't you build a graph data structure from a list? (OTH, I don't think brute-force solving the TSP with 200 cities is feasible).

Comment: How is this different that the classic tsm?

Comment: Can you provide the complete 200 records? Also, your example is weird? Should it be `LosAngeles`? Why only a dash after `NewYork`?